# Error 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric' - Create new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table "Table1_201403" with 1 varchar column 'Column 0'. Now, I want to insert the necessary data from this table to Master_Table2 with the query below -

```
SELECT '2014/03' AS Period
    ,ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 1, 12))) AS 'Account'
    ,cast(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 17, 2))) + ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 15, 2))) + ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 13, 2))) AS DATE) AS Trans_Date
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 30, 1))) = '-'
            THEN CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))) AS DECIMAL) / 100) AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) * - 1
        ELSE CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))) AS DECIMAL) / 100) AS DECIMAL(9, 2))
        END AS Amount
INTO Master_Table2
FROM Table1_201403
WHERE SUBSTRING([Column 0], 11, 1) <> 'B'
```

When I try to do this, I get the error 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'.

What can be a suitable solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Modified -

```
    SELECT '2014/03' AS Period
    ,ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 1, 12))) AS 'GL Account'
    ,cast(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 17, 2))) + ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 15, 2))) + ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 13, 2))) AS DATE) AS Trans_Date
    ,case
        when ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 30, 1))) = '-'
                                THEN( 
                                        case when isnumeric(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))))=1 then            
                                        CAST(CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2)) AS decimal)*-1 
                                        else 
                                        CAST(CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2)) AS varchar)*-1 end
                                    )
                                ELSE(

                                        case when isnumeric(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))))=1 then            
                                        CAST(CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2)) AS decimal) 
                                        else 
                                        CAST(CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2)) AS varchar) end
                                    )
            END  as Amount
            INTO TABLE2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE SUBSTRING([Column 0], 11, 1) <> 'B'
```

I tried using the IsNumeric Logic. But could not get the code working. Please have a look.
@Adi T

And, the data is as below got using your script @t_m -

Column 0    ValidDecimal
006125      01031400000451745+        JNLCIS Batch 01/03/2014                                                          N        BA0119           C                 L                                                                                                                            1
006125      01031400000212077+        JNLCIS Batch 01/03/2014                                                          N        BA0120           C                 L                                                                                                                            1
006125      01031400000311569+        JNLCIS Batch 01/03/2014                                                          N        BA0119           P                 L                                                                                                                            1

Comment: `What can be a suitable solution.` Doesn't the error message tell you?  Stop trying to insert a varchar into a numeric field.  Convert it to numeric using CAST or CONVERT.

Comment: I tried casting as numeric but not help. Can u please help me further.

Comment: Code edited with the IsNumeric logic but not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Have a suspicion that the Amount logic may be returning some varchar value instead of decimal.

Run the script below to check your amount logic is correct. When you run the script you should not return any records if all is OK.

```
    select *
from 
(
    select '2014/03' as Period,
    ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],1,12))) as 'Account', 
    cast(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],17,2)))+ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],15,2)))+ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],13,2))) AS DATE) 
    as Trans_Date,
    ISNUMERIC(case when ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],30,1)))='-' then CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2))*-1
            else CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2)) END) As ValidDecimal
    from Table1_201403
    where SUBSTRING([Column 0],11,1) <> 'B' 
) CheckForValidDecimal
where ValidDecimal = 0
```

**Modified:**

Run this script below to find your [Column 0] records that are incorrect. You can then change your Amount logic to fix the problem.

```
    select *
from 
(
    select 
    [Column 0], 
    ISNUMERIC(case when ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],30,1)))='-' then CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2))*-1
            else CAST((CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0],19,11))) AS decimal) / 100) AS decimal(9,2)) END) As ValidDecimal
    from Table1_201403
    where SUBSTRING([Column 0],11,1) <> 'B' 
) CheckForValidDecimal
where ValidDecimal = 0
```

Comment: It returns records with the valid decimal field being 0.00 in all the cases. So, what would be a suitable way around.

Comment: Posted modified script to find problem records. You can then fix the Amount logic.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to convert the data from varchar to decimal.if the data belongs to charachters you can't able to convert to decimal.

```
use cast() or convert() function
```

Comment: I tried casting as numeric but not help. Can u please help me further.

Comment: isnumeric(column)=1 then convert() ...this one works.i have done lots of times

Comment: isnumeric(column)=1 then convert(to decimal) else convert(to varchar)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

```
SELECT '2014/03' AS Period
        ,ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 1, 12))) AS 'Account'
        ,cast(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 17, 2))) + ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 15, 2))) + ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 13, 2))) AS DATE) AS Trans_Date
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 30, 1))) = '-'
                THEN case when isnumeric( case when isnumeric(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))
                ))=1 then            
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS decimal) else 
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS varchar) end)=1
                then CAST(case when isnumeric(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))
                ))=1 then            
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS decimal) else 
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS varchar) end AS decimal(9,2)) *-1
                else 
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS varchar)
                ELSE
                  CAST(case when isnumeric(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11))
                ))=1 then            
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS decimal) else 
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS varchar) end AS decimal(9,2)) /100 AS DECIMAL
                else 
                CAST(ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING([Column 0], 19, 11)))AS varchar)
                END 
                INTO Master_Table2
    FROM Table1_201403
    WHERE SUBSTRING([Column 0], 11, 1) <> 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it is giving me some error if the if-then-else conditions.

Comment: may be becz of the end statements.i didnot keep properily becz i donot have source table.100% this way will work.i have done many times

Comment: You cannot CAST the Amount column to be VARCHAR and DECIMAL. This is why you are getting the error. @anir .. Can you post some data from teh modified script that I posted?